# Fuduntu not recognized by GRUB

Tags: grub-legacy

Yesterday I installed FUDUNTU. During the install my MBR (I use ubuntu as my main OS) was overwritten. When I recovered the MBR I discovered that FUDUNTU was not listed. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Fedora and Fuduntu use (as far as I understand) - legacy Grub.

I would restore [Grub 2 to your MBR](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling_GRUB2) using your Ubuntu Live CD, then boot with your Fuduntu live CD (I'm presuming there is such a thing) and install Grub onto the root of the Fuduntu partition - please ask on the Fedora/Fuduntu forums on how to do this if you are unsure how to reinstall Grub into the Fuduntu partition.

Reboot into normal Ubuntu and re-run

```
sudo update-grub
```

This should put both Funduntu and Ubuntu into Grub 2

---

[How To Boot Into Ubuntu 11.04 After Installing Fedora 15](http://www.muktware.com/articles/25/2011/1231)